# Iterate through row to compare with ascii value in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ascii

I've a column which contains strings

like

```
id fruit

1  apple
2  mango
3  banana
4  grapes
5  watermelon
```

I need to iterate through the fruit row to find out where is ascii value of `a` which is 97.

like in id=1 apple contains `'a'=97` so i want to print the `position of character a` in all
rows by comparing it with ascii value 97.

can anybody tell me how to iterate through each row to compare with ascii value 97?

Comment: Where the value contains more than one instance of the specified character, as is the case with 'a' in 'banana', what would you expect to be returned?

Comment: I think you have "row" and "column" understanding confused, each instance of id/fruit is a row and each of those (id, fruit) is a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CHARINDEX((CHAR(97), fruit)
FROM MyTable
```

This uses the `CHARINDEX` function, which gives the first position of a character within a string, and the `CHAR()` function, which returns a character assigned to the ascii value given.

Comment: `SELECT CHARINDEX('vishA',ascii(65))`; why this query returns 0 when ascii value 65 is associated with A.

Comment: @user1095881 - Because `ASCII()` turns a CHAR into an INT - it gets the ascii vaue for a character. Try using `CHAR(65)` to return `'A'`.

Comment: @Dems SELECT `CHARINDEX('vishA',char(65));` still it returns 0

Comment: @user1095881 it's fixed now.  The string to find comes first, THEN the string to look in.